# How can I do Threads in NodeJs ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, web-worker

I want to move to the next iteration only if the function generateTilesIfReady has finished executing

```
 for (var i = 0; i<dataFilePaths.length; i++){
            generateTilesIfReady(tilePaths[i], dataFilePaths[i], dataSetNames[i]);
          }
```

How can I do this on NodeJs ?

Comment: You can use Async for it. https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/napajs also looks like it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not mentioned what `generateTilesIfReady` returns. Lets assume it returns promise.

If you are on node 8 or above, you can use async, await and write something like this

```
const generateTilesIfReady = (i) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('test'), 3000));

}

async function runnerFunction () {
  for (var i = 0; i< 5; i++){
    const result = await generateTilesIfReady(i);
    console.log(result);
  }
}
runnerFunction();
```

For lower version of nodes, you can use [async library times operator](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times)

```
const async = require("async");

const generateTilesIfReady = (i, callback) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(null, i);
  }, 200);
}

function runnerFunction () {
  async.times(5, function(n, next) {
    generateTilesIfReady(n, function (err, result) {
      next(err, result)
    });
  }, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
}

runnerFunction();
```

Comment: The generateTilesIfReady function does not return anything, it does big traietemnts and it makes calls to APIs

Comment: I have Node v4.8.4

Comment: @AlaeddineBAGHDADI Updated the answer for lower version of node